# Ropes in cocos2d/box2d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

Hello guys I have been experimenting with Cocos2d and box2d recently. I am trying to draw ropes as in games like Bunny Shooter, Cut the rope etc.. But I did not get any leads. I found out a class called VRope, but I am pretty unsure how to use it.

What I aim to produce is something like a hanging rope which when cut at a point produces animation similar to real ropes pretty like in the Bunny Shooter etc.. I have found this in many games. Any one having any idea?

It would be great if you could give me some hints or a good tutorial link.

Thank You